# D3, Google Maps, selecting d3 elements

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, selection, d3.js

Per this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/1125458), I am trying to add marker selection, (i.e. add .on("click"...) to the marker variable). However, when you bring the mouse over the google maps canvas, you get the hand that lets you drag, and you cannot select any svg elements with it.

Is there a way to (temporary) disable that feature so you can click the D3 elements?

Comment: Maybe you could try getting [selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) of all/some elements of the map, and overwriting the handlers with empty functions? Like so `d3.selectAll("%gmaps elements%").on("drag", function() {return})`

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on building a map like this right now. I haven't used Google's markers (rather d3 SVG circles) but I found mouseover/click/etc events had to be on objects in the overlayMouseTarget layer of the map:

```
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

overlay.onAdd = function() {

    var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget)
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "providers");
             ...
}
```

I think the gMaps demo on d3js.org uses a different layer.

Comment: Thanks, gave me enough info to find the documentation on this. Examples like [bl.ocks.org's Google maps + d3](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711) often use the `overlayLayer` maps layer which does not receive click events. Further [documentation on devopers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays#initialize) confirms that only layers `overlayMouseTarget` and `floatPane` receive DOM events.

Answer (score 2):

You can use     var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView(); overlay.onAdd function

```
 overlay.onAdd = function () {
    var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget)
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "stations");
   }
```

To draw the custom markers`overlay.draw`

and `overlay.setMap()` to bind our overlay to the map…

More info can be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays